# Java access frame

Tags: java, swing, awt

Im trying the following code using java.swing and java.awt

**Init.java**

```
package es.com.gui;

import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class init extends JFrame
{
    public init()
    {       
        // Start the actual GUI

        setTitle("Basic calculator");
        setSize(300, 300);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Add some GUI elements

        constructor constructor = new constructor();

        JTextField input1 = constructor.addTextField("e"); 
        input1.setColumns(25);

    }
}
```

**Constructor.java**

```
package es.com.gui;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class constructor extends JFrame
{
    public JLabel addLabel(String text)
    {
         JLabel label = new JLabel(text);
         add(label);

         return label;
    }

    public JButton addButton(String text)
    {
        JButton button = new JButton(text);
        add(button);

        return button;
    }

    public JTextField addTextField(String text)
    {
        JTextField textArea = new JTextField(text);
        add(textArea);

        return textArea;
    }
}
```

The thing is I want to have the functions to construct new GUI elements on another class and heres my problem
If I add that functions into Init.java everything works fine but adding them into Constructor.java seems to not work (no error at all, elements never appear)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a specific example of the general question,

> How can I call methods of one object from within another object.

And one possible solution is to pass references.  For example you could change your Constructor's constructor to accept an Init object and use it to initialize an Init field, init:

```
public class Constructor {
  private Init init;

  public Constructor(Init init) {
    this.init = init;
  }

  // now you can use the init as your Init instance throughout this class
```

and then pass `this` in when calling this constructor.

As an aside: Please read up and follow Java naming conventions including giving classes names that start with upper case letters (see my code above as an example).

Answer (score 2):

What you probably want to do is extend your "Constructor" from JPanel, not JFrame. And add following to your Init():

```
add(constructor);
```

JFrame is basically a class for Window creation. As i can see you don't need another window but you want elements to appear in your Init() window.